# Error in if (alpha < 0) alpha <- 0 : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

I am working with a statistical analysis called STARS written in R. It was prewritten code given to me that I am trying to make work for my palaeoecological data.

I keep getting stuck on this one line of code:

```
PC1stars = stars(rev(PC1Bin1), L=15, p=0.05,  h=1, AR1red="est", prewhitening = T)
```

and I continue to get this error:

```
Error in if (alpha < 0) alpha <- 0 : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I have searched `?stars` to see if I can fix the problem but all of my attempts are not working. Can anyone point me in the right direction where I am going wrong with the code?

Comment: Sounds like you might have `NA` values in your input data that need to be removed. As in `if (NA < 0) print("hello")` which fails in an identical fashion.

Comment: Is this related to [`STAR`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/STAR/index.html)? If not, you need to provide context to your question.